# In-App purchases does not work in all Simulators

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios-simulator

While testing Xcode 5 in various simulators (iPad/iPhone and iOS6.1 and iOS7), some of the simulators are able to load in-app purchases, while others are not.

I can see not way to change the Settings in the Simulator to make up for the difference in behaviour.

The code being used in all cases is:

```
[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: productIdentifiers];
```

and the list of productIdentifiers is always the same.

Comment: store kit is not working on simulators. Testing is available only on real device

Comment: not in all? in none and it is documented like that

Answer (score 2):

In app purchase is not a feature you can use on the iOS simulator (not unlike push notifications, CoreMotion and some other frameworks).

To work with StoreKit, you'll have to run on an actual device.

From:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241

> > StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

Given the amount of times Apple have allowed this feature and then broke it, I'd stay away from testing IAP on the simulator altogether.

Comment: Note that this isn't intentional, it's a known bug as documented in the link. The simulator *should* allow IAPs.